# Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'. bitstream-charter

Tags: fonts, errors

I am trying to use the following package:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

but I am having the following error:

> LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value 'mc'.
> It should not contain an 'm'! Please correct it.

Does anyone now hot to fix this problem?
After getting this error, the file is not being generated.

Sample of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Comment: I took my best guess what problem you’re having (since I’ve run into a similar one), but without a MWE, it’s impossible to tell. Please always include a MWE.

Comment: This is not an error, but only a warning (see [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/299)). You should simply ignore it.

Comment: If you simply ignore it, some font commands (such as small caps and oldstyle numbers) won’t work. Loading `XCharter`/`erewhon`/`garamondx` depending on whether you wanted `charter`, `utopia` or `garamond`, will fix them.

Comment: @gman I have added a sample of my preamble, I am not sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably trying to use `mathdesign`.  If possible, disable its `expert` option, which is obsolete.  If you are trying to use

```
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

Add the line immediately below.

```
\usepackage{XCharter}
```

If you were instead trying to use `[utopia]`, add the line

```
\usepackage{erewhon}
```

If you were trying to use Garamond, load

```
\usepackage{garamondx}
```

The `mathdesign` package attempts to redefine the meaning of commands such as `\mdseries` and `\scshape` in a way that breaks them, not just for the main font, but for all fonts.  This was apparently a too-clever by-half workaround for some non-standard filenames back in the ’90s, and the package authors never provided a way to turn it off.  The warning about `mc` happens to be harmless, but the redefinition of small caps is not.

The `XCharter`/`erewhon`/`garamondx` package not only loads the free version of the same font, it also loads `fontaxes`, which as a side effect fixes those commands back up again.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem at all. Secondly, I have a hard time understanding your rant about Charter, which has been donated by Bitstream to the community (so it is "free" and is included in TL). Also, your claim that the font "apparently used different series and shape parameters than every other font ever made" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Robert I can rephrase if you think I was too critical of the `mathdesign` package, but the fix I posted does solve the problem. (The OP will still get the warning messages, but they’ll become harmless.)

Comment: @Robert To clarify, it’s precisely because Bitstream donated Charter to the X Consortium, and that version has been repackaged for LaTeX, that nobody today has the old version of Bitstream Charter from the ’90s that `mathdesign` attempts to load. If the package were still being maintained, someone would have rewritten it either to load the free modern forks of those fonts, or not to muck up the text font commands at all.

Comment: The warnings are harmless in either case, with or without `XCharter` (and IMHO they [shouldn't be issued at all](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/289#issuecomment-599001442))

Comment: @Robert It does, however, actually break small caps.

Comment: You're conflating `charter` and  `mathdesign`. The Charter fonts adhere to the NFSS naming scheme by the book. Also, they are in `collection-fontsrecommended`, so probably everybody has them (try `\renewcommand\rmdefault{bch}`).

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the correction. Then `mathdesign` is just broken. It’s still worthwhile to load `XCharter` for the small caps and oldstyle figures, but I removed the inaccurate paragraph.

Comment: So there's no way to stop this warning from cropping up all the time when using `bitstream-charter`? Or is this just a flaw with the `mathdesign` package? If I used a different font, would this error appear still?

Comment: @SkeletonBow It’s a flaw with `mathdesign`, but it’s possible to write a patch to suppress the warnings. I’ve done it for small caps before. If I have the time later, I’ll do some investigation.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! I would have looked but I have absolutely no idea where I'd start looking (or what to do if I found an issue)

Comment: Awsome answer! (+1)